# Dynamic padding between UI controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my Windows Forms Application project, there were 3 buttons side by side. I wanted dynamic padding between each buttons. My goal was that when I resize the UI at runtime, the distance between the buttons to change proportionally, by keeping buttons' size.

As a solution, I've modified the **anchor** properties that left buttons anchor is **top-left**, middle button's is only **top** and finally right button's is **top-right**. Everything was fine until the 4th button need.

My question is how can I get the same behavior/result with 4 buttons?

Comment: Use TableLayout Panel with 1 row and 3 columns. Each cell contains a button. Set button anchors to none. Set the column size modes to percent, each 100%

Comment: ... No matter how many buttons you have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Use the `TableLayoutPanel` with following settings:

- 1 row and a few columns (based on your requirement)
- Columns should have `SizeType` = Percent and each column size = 100% (so they will occupy equal space).
- Each cell should contain a button having `Anchor` = None (so each button will be placed at center of the cell, horizontally and vertically centered.)
- You can set `TableLayoutPanel`  `Dock` = Bottom or set `Anchor` = Left, Right, Bottom.

[image]

To learn more about `TableLayoutPanel`, you may find the following links useful:

- [How to lay out your form with a TableLayoutPanel control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/step-4-lay-out-your-form-with-a-tablelayoutpanel-control?view=vs-2019&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [How to: Anchor and Dock Child Controls in a TableLayoutPanel Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-anchor-and-dock-child-controls-in-a-tablelayoutpanel-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [Best Practices for the TableLayoutPanel Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/best-practices-for-the-tablelayoutpanel-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [TableLayoutPanel class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: Great! No problem :)